# Google Secrets Manager Denied Access When Roles/Poject/ServiceAccount Correct?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

This is truly boggling my mind. I am using Python and trying to pull the secrets manager value from a resource that I have access to from what I can tell. I'm on Windows using Python 3.8.

```
def fetch_credentials():
    project_id = "109837978792"  # Anonymized for Stack
    secret_id = "some_secret_name"
    version_id = "1"
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})
    payload = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    print("Plaintext: {}".format(payload))
```

**Error**

google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'secretmanager.secrets.get' denied for resource 'projects/109837978792/secrets/some_secret_name/versions/1' (or it may not exist).

"grpc_message":"Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource

**Configuration**

- gcloud shows my project name, ID, and number on list.
- gcloud shows my-serviceaccount@myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com on auth list and it's selected.
- console shows IAM roles for service account as: Owner, DLP User, and Secret Manager Secret Accessor.
- console shows the service account key as active and in JSON form. Expires Dec 31, 9999.
- console shows the secret as active and at path: projects/109837978792/secrets/some_secret_name
- console shows the secret is on version 1
- console shows the secret specific IAM roles are inherited for service account on secret name.
- console shows secrets manager API and Cloud Resource Manager API active on project.
- console shows secret manager activity in graphs from failed calls.
- windows has set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:/etc/service_account.json

**Bindings**

```
{
  "role": "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor",
  "members": [
    "serviceAccount:my-serviceaccount@myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  ]
}
```

Same roles are set for my gmail. If I use my gmail account to login using gcloud auth login, it still fails when it has same roles for same project. What am I missing here?

Comment: 1) Is the Secret Manager API enabled: `gcloud services enable secretmanager.googleapis.com`? 2) Can you access the secret with the CLI: `gcloud secrets versions access VERSION_ID --secret=SECRET_ID`?

Comment: Yes to both. Response is the secret value I set in console. I'm going to assume there is an issue with my Python package and finding the credentials through ServiceAccountCredentials. Any way to validate how it is authenticating? gcloud is set to the service account and project I pulled the secret from above.

Comment: SecretManagerServiceClient().from_service_account_file('service_account.json') works for the service account. Which, proves the service_account key is working and has permissions. So the big question is, why is SecretManagerServiceClient on it's own, not using the service account or any account activated from the gcloud auth list or projects?

Comment: Setup auth using this command: `gcloud auth application-default login` Also make sure you are using the latest libraries.

Comment: Did that already. That's just authenticating with my gmail user. Not the service account. When I do gcloud auth application-default login to my personal user, which has same access to the project and is owner. I still get permission issues. It's wierd.

Comment: This setting overrides everything `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:/etc/service_account.json`

Comment: Yup did that too. Even set it as the Windows environmental variable from advanced settings too.

Comment: I meant delete that setting.

Comment: I think your issue is that you do not understand how ADC works (Application Default Credentials).

Comment: I absolutely do. I read your freaking article on it. I understand Secrets is looking for the environmental variable first. Hence why it's set. It should work. I don't use service account for all the code because Google doesn't support service accounts for all products. But all is set correctly from what I can see both through gcloud and using environmental variable to set the key location. Please enlighten me on where this is failing?

Comment: Your comment that this line of code works `SecretManagerServiceClient().from_service_account_file('service_account.json')`. That means ADC is set up wrong or incorrectly. Undo the steps you did with authorization and start over.

Comment: I figured it out, will post answer. It was the environmental setting for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS was not being overritten for some reason. I set it, execute SET and see the value. Then it will reset. Likely with admin privileges on my Windows machine. Restarting fixed it (silly enough). Now the environmental variable is set to correct keyfile and it works.